# Dialogflow Unify Responses cross multiple platforms

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

Is there any way I can unify the responses in dialgflow across multiple platforms?

I'm building a chatbot where users can interact with using:

1. Facebook Messenger
2. Custom API Endpoints

In the dialogflow console, I can specify the response on facebook that is different than the default response

### Default Response

[image: Default Response]

### Facebook Response

[image: Facebook Response]

But i do want buttons to appear on both responses. Is there any way to do that?

I do understand that Facebook requires the response to be in a specific format in order to interpret the buttons... and I'm free to set any custom payload in the default response that can be interpreted by the client ( App, website ), but did anyone manage to combine both responses?

If not, what's a good way to set the custom payload? any examples might help.

**Note**: Webhook calls are enabled for all intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send custom payloads in the JSON format provided in the platforms documentation, it will be rendered on a specific platform accordingly. Below is the format which you need to follow to send custom payload.

```
{
  "facebook": {
  },
  "kik": {
  },
  "line": {
  },
  "skype": {
  },
  "slack": {
  },
  "telegram": {
  }
  "viber": {
  }
}
```

[image: custom-payload]

You can also send a custom payload to self-developed integrations. It won’t be processed by Dialogflow, so you'll need to handle it in your own business logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I see. but the issue is that with facebook, payload must include the recipient id. This means that the response can't be set in the console right? or is there a way to fill these from the request ?

Comment: you can send the custom payload in the webhook response as well.